# Inventory/Stock Monitoring Database Schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I tried my best, asked IRC for help but still kinda hard.

[Here's what I only got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJLYk.png)
I don't know how would I link medicines to products.

Here's the logic:

- Many brands can make many products.
- Products can have many brands, has name, and image
- Products have type (it may be Medicine, Soap, etc)
- If product is medicine, I want to it to be attached to the medicines tables as it's attribute will be inserted there.

examples:

- Brand A - Product A - image1 - Medicine - 250 - mg
- Brand B - Product A - image2 - Medicine - 250 - mg
- Brand B - Product A - image2 - Medicine - 500 - mg
- Brand B - Product B - image 3 - Soap
- Brand B - Product C - image 4- Soap

-- EDIT --

I thought of adding medicine_fk on the products table. It'll be null if it's not a medicine. But thinking about its flexibility, what if in the future there will be more product types?

A good example (bad type tho xD)

I'll be needing car_fk in the product table? that points to car table?
How should I do that?

-- EDIT --

My mind's is so stressed about this one I forgot I should put the product_id instead on car table and medicine table and any other types of products

-- EDIT --

At first I thought how to find all the tables that is related to the product if ever a user added a new product type.

And thought of making another table again, and also dynamically making new tables for each product types but that seems an ugly way.

With the help of IRC people I ended up with this:

[image: 2]]

Is there any possible errors with that?

-- EDIT --

My FINAL table structure is the same as above only without the sub tables.

- I removed subattributes and sub categories.
- Add a parent_id column on categories and attributes table instead.

Much better and I assumed this answered my question.

Comment: Is one medicine exactly one product? Or is there a many-to-many-relation? Or is are many products one medicine?

Comment: One product (Aspirin) may have many medicine attributes, there 250mg and 500mg right?

Comment: It sounds to me as if using all four columns of your medicine table with id the same as the id in products (so a product_fk) would describe your model.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your diagram the relationship between PRODUCT_TYPES and PRODUCTS is depicted as one-to-one, shouldn't this relationship be one- to-many (One product type can have many products for example Medicine can have Asprin, Paracetamol etc).

Secondly, the approach you are following is correct. Just introduce your PRODUCT_ID in your medicines table and your CAR table. It should be NOT NULL. Since PRODUCTS is your parent table it should not have the keys from other tables.

Alternately, you could also make the ID in your medicines table as a foreign key to the ID column in your PRODUCTS table.

Comment: Sorry about the 1-1 too. First time using Workbench, I just forgot editing the relationship everytime I made one

Comment: I would not recommend storing attributes and their values in generic columns. With such a design you will not be able to ensure if each value is of the correct data type. For example if any of your attributes is of date datatype and a malformed date string is inserted into it the database will allow the same. Whereas having a correct data type will ensure that no such junk data gets into your database. Further, querying such data is going to be another challenge.

Comment: I am aware of that but would you rather dynamically make table for every types? If you know any other way aside from that it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that relationships should be 1:many or many:many, never 1:1.  Only in the many:many case do you need an extra table.

"Sub" attributes and categories will be a nightmare to deal with; can you get rid of them?

What will the `SELECTs` be?  To some extend, they drive what the tables look like.

A table with a thousand rows does not need its fields "normalized".

Comment: Any examples so I can clearly understand what you mean by "A table with a thousand rows does not need its fields "normalized"."?